# Aplicação com vraptor lenta após atualizar java e tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, vraptor

Estou trabalhando em uma aplicação legada e a aplicação ao natural já é um pouco lenta, acredito que pela maneira que foi desenvolvida, porém após atualizar a versão do java 7 para java 8 e tomcat 7 para tomcat 8 a aplicação demora quase 2 minutos para carregar a tela inicial, antes demorava no máximo uns 10 segundos.

- vraptor 3.4.1
- tomcat 8.0.47
- jdk 8

Acredito que a lentidão esteja ocorrendo pela entrega extremamente lenta de conteúdo ao browser, pois todos os requests estão demorando muito para serem concluídos, alguns exemplos:

- bootstrap.min.css 19.6k: 10.07 segundos para download
- font-awsome.min.css 5.7k: 20.27 segundos para download

Esses tempos foram retirados do browser com a aplicação rodando localhost.

Eu poderia fornecer diversos exemplos, mas todos seguem um padrão definido: os 6 primeiros arquivos (quantidade máxima de requests paralelos do browser) levam todos no mínimo 10 segundos, os próximos 6 levam no mínimo 20 segundos e assim por diante.

Sei que estou fornecendo pouquíssimas informações mas eu realmente não sei qual o motivo da lentidão e nem por onde começar.

Alguém poderia me ajudar por favor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aparentemente o problema era um filter no web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>compressionFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.googlecode.webutilities.filters.CompressionFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param> 
        <param-name>compressionThreshold</param-name>
        <param-value>1024</param-value> <!-- compress anything above 1kb -->
    </init-param>
    <init-param> 
        <param-name>ignoreURLPattern</param-name>
        <param-value>.*\.(flv|mp3|mpg)</param-value> <!-- regex -->
    </init-param>
    <init-param> 
        <param-name>ignoreMimes</param-name>
        <param-value>images/*,video/*, multipart/x-gzip</param-value> <!-- ignore -->
    </init-param>
    <init-param> 
        <param-name>ignoreUserAgentsPattern</param-name>
        <param-value>.*MSIE.*</param-value> <!-- regex -->
    </init-param>
 </filter>
 <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>compressionFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>
```

Removi todo esse filter e tudo voltou a funcionar normalmente.

Sobre o vrapto4 eu tentei atualizar, mas como o projeto tem MUITAS classes que são personalizadas e com libs mais antigas (tem muitas libs de 2005, 2006 e 2007) ficou complicado de ir atrás de todas as soluções para resolver todos os métodos depreciados, removidos e que pararam de funcionar das libs.